# Minix keyboard Driver

Tags: c, driver, minix

I'm trying to change the keyboard driver in minix, my idea is store in a file all the characters that the used introduced in the keyboard.I declare a global FILE * fp and insert this piece of code in /usr/src/drivers/tty/keyboard.c

```
while (icount > 0) {
         scode = *itail++;      /* take one key scan code */
          if (itail == ibuf + KB_IN_BYTES) itail = ibuf;
          icount--;

          /* Function keys are being used for debug dumps. */
          if (func_key(scode)) continue;

           /* Perform make/break processing. */
           ch = make_break(scode);

           if (ch <= 0xFF) {
                  /* A normal character. */

                  fp = fopen("log.txt","a+");
                  fprint(fp,"%c",ch);
                  fclose(fp);

                   buf[0] = ch;
                   (void) in_process(tp, buf, 1);
          } else ...
```

then I run "make" in the directory and reboot but this does not work. I mean, the file is not created.
Any idea?

Comment: "...does not work" is a little hazy. Please edit your question and add some additional information about what "does not work". Is it too slow? Doesn't write the keys to the file? Opens a gateway between the worlds through which ooze pestilential creatures of foulest evil?

Comment: If you are _truly_ modifying the keyboard _driver_ (ie. it's in the minux kernel), you won't be able to use `stdio.h` style streams [unless minux is different from every other unix kernel I've ever used]. You'll have to use the internal minix functions for I/O. And, doing `open, write one char, close` is _extremely_ inefficient [and can lead to complications]. Open the log file _once_

Comment: But I think that minix drivers belongs to user space, and in this minix tutorial uses the stdlib functions... http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:driverprogramming

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. The keyboard driver is inside the `TTY` "driver", a service which is in charge of the console. `FS`/`VFS` will transmit the I/O requests concerning that console to `TTY`. `fopen`, `fprint`, and `fclose` in your code are ways to perform such requests. But `VFS` can only handle requests from "user" programs (and transmit them down to drivers); `TTY` is not a "user" program, and as such, is not allowed to perform I/O requests.

Comment: Yet, OP runs "make" and somehow thinks it built.

Comment: @AntonieL I´m sorry but you're wrong, the program works fine, the problem was that I was running "make" in other directory...

Comment: OK, I am wrong since I misunderstood that the program you wrote was not `TTY` (which source is in `/usr/src/drivers/tty/keyboard.c`), and your unidentified program is fine. Sorry for the time lost.

Also, you better abstain to rebuild the kernel.